# ubuntu 16.04: does davfs2 honor DNS TTL and re-resolves the entry while mounted?

Tags: ubuntu, webdav, davfs2

I was provided with a WebDAV storage server, that I want to mount on a productive Ubuntu 16.04 server using `davfs2`. The storage server is connected to using a DNS name; its actual IP might change due to load balancing, failover or maintenance reasons. I want the mount to be as stable and available as possible without any manual intervention needed.

The DNS record has a TTL of a few seconds set. Will `davfs2` honor the TTL and connect to another IP if the DNS entry is changed? Do you have any other proposal on how to get this as stable as possible?

[Edit]
This question is about the **specific** behavior of `davfs2`, and should imho be therefore not considered a duplicate of the question related to `cifs` mentioned by 2 users.

Comment: DNS is not a solution for creating high availability.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro you're right, but for that use case a very small interruption might be acceptable. Most important is that no manual intervention is needed. In addition the storage operator tries to let the old IP stay operable for a multiple timespan of the TTL to allow for a switch.

Comment: Leaving high availability solutions on the hands of clients is noot a good idea. I would use a clustering solution.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477105/mounting-cifs-share-with-linux-4-15-do-dns-names-get-resolved-again-in-case-of?noredirect=1#comment875005_477105

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mounting cifs share with Linux 4.15: do DNS names get resolved again in case of errors?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477105/mounting-cifs-share-with-linux-4-15-do-dns-names-get-resolved-again-in-case-of)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the questions are related, but are targetting different technologies. Would you see the questions whether apples should be stored in the fridge and whether this applies for oranges as well also treat as duplicates?

Comment: @RalfFriedl please see my comment for RuiFRibeiro. Why do you see two questions, that for sure target one scenario, but are referring to completely different technologies (davfs2, cifs) as duplicates?